# Accessing socket.io in koa route

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0, koa

I'm trying to use socket.io with koa.js and I was able to connect adding `server = require('http').createServer(koa.callback()).listen(port);` and `io = require('socket.io')(server);` at the very bottom of my application but now I want to emit and if possible listen to events from my controller / route. What's the best way to implement this?

I've tried adding `io` in my koa context like `koa.context.io = io` and even `io.on('connection', function(socket){ koa.context.socket = socket });` but nothing is working.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Reason could be because of initialise order: http://spathon.com/koa-js-and-socket-io/

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the socket.io instance in your koa route should not work.

Creating the socket.io instance depends on the application creating a callback function that can be used by the http server.

```
var server = http.createServer(app.callback());
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

This callback is generated with the help of co and requires that your app is already set up with all the middleware/routes. (see the [koa source](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/7b3e3cbad51dfa66fa7aa81bb74a93419c3a19c9/lib/application.js#L113)). Therefore you can't use the socket.io instance (which is created afterwards) in those routes.

Furthermore I think it is not intended to emit socket.io events in your controllers. If you want to send data back to the client that called the controller, you should do it in the response which is generated by that controller. If you want to emit further events at the server you could trigger them from the client by emitting an event that the server will receive. This way you can process the data from the client in the function you pass to `socket.on(...)` and don't need to implement it in the controller/routes for koa.

Here is an example for the second case, without any koa controller/route.

app.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var koa = require('koa');
var app = koa();
var send = require('koa-send');

app.use(function* (next) {
  if (this.path !== '/') return yield next;
  yield send(this, __dirname + '/index.html');
});

var server = http.createServer(app.callback());
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('click', function (data) {
    //process the data here
    console.log('client clicked! data:');
    console.log(data);

    // emit an event
    console.log('responding with news');
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  });
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port);
console.log ('Listening at port ' + port + ' ...');
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>koa-socket.io</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
      console.log('received news with data: ');
      console.log(data);
    });

    function myclick () {
      console.log("click");
      socket.emit('click', { clickdata: 'i clicked the button' });
    }

  </script>

  <button type="button" onclick="myclick();">Click Me and watch console at server and in browser.</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is a little late on the uptake, and could be deemed slightly self-serving as I'm going to suggest one of my own modules, but, you're on the right track with appending it to the app, with Koa v2 this is easier as the context is passed right along but with v1 you can tack it onto `this`, as koa middleware's are bound to the app instance.

Alternatively, I wrote a module to help with this exact use-case, https://github.com/mattstyles/koa-socket, it does just 2 things currently (and probably forever): it appends the socket.io server instance to the context and it allows you to write koa-style middleware for your socket listeners.

Comment: Matt! I'm actually using your module right now. :) I'm having trouble though as the initial polling requests are failing. Is this due socket.io not attaching correctly to my koa app instance? I'm stuck :p

Comment: Hi @Askdesigners, if its related to the module can you open an issue with a few more details and we can try and get it fixed up